# How do I set AFrame position using variables and javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax, aframe

When I use:

```
myObject.setAttribute('position','3 0 35' );
```

everything works fine.

I want to set attributes from variables,
instead of having to manually type in the numbers,
like this:

```
myObject.setAttribute('position','myX myY myZ' );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: myObject.setAttribute('position' , 'x' ,  myX  ); works. But now all numbers are positive. I had negative and positive numbers in an array and it is looping through them to set item positions. I didn't do this in the DOM initially because I'm cloning the objects, and they are all in the exact same place until I move them.

Comment: This worked fine in THREE.js, and I'm using almost the same loop to try it in AFrame, and failing.

Comment: function ArrangeSeating2(){   //[]forEach table and chair set, spacing Horizontal and vertical.  make it 4x8 for 32 students?
 ODesk = Desk3DP(0,0); //O-Riginal Desk
 OChair=Chair3DP(0,0); //O-Riginal Chair
 deskNo =[ [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[] ];
 chairNo=[ [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[] ];

Comment: var spC=[-108,-60,-24,24,60,108]; var d=72;
 for (k=0; k<8; k++){
  for(l=0; l<6; l++){
     deskNo[k][l] = ODesk.clone();  deskNo[k][l].position.x=spC[l];  deskNo[k][l].position.z=d; scene.add(deskNo[k][l])  ; deskNo[k][l].name='desk-0'+k+l;  nn=String(k)+String(l);  deskNo[k][l].children[0].name+=nn;  deskNo[k][l].children[1].name+=nn;

Comment: chairNo[k][l] = OChair.clone(); chairNo[k][l].position.x=spC[l]; chairNo[k][l].position.z=d+12; scene.add(chairNo[k][l]) ; chairNo[k][l].name='chair-0'+k+l; nn=String(k)+String(l); chairNo[k][l].children[0].name+=nn; chairNo[k][l].children[1].name+=nn;
  }
    d += 50;
 }
}

Comment: Each set in named 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 - 10 11 12 13 14 etc... first digit being the x-axis position from the array(row), and the second digit of the name for the z axis (column). also.. the newer ones are now moving the older ones, so EVERYTHING goes to the back right, 68 position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to preposition them too quickly, the loop created them, but I was trying to move them before they were fully loaded into the scene.
The room is so dense with objects that it took longer than expected.

Aframe being a higher level language, it takes longer to load.
Three.js loaded more quickly, but the AFrame animations seem smoother.
I will just need a "loading" message to keep people from thinking it is broken.

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject.setAttribute('position',myX+" "+ myY+" "+myZ);'
```

You need to construct a string...

Comment: Or another option: `el.setAttribute('position', {x: myX, y: myY, z: myZ});`.

Comment: I will post another question about the positive/negative problem.

Comment: The string method is causing all integers to become positive.

Answer (score 0):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#adding-a-component-with-setattribute

`el.setAttribute('position', {x: myX, y: myY, z: myZ});`